# Difference between form.submit and window.open() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a javascript function which redirects to another page with the parent page contents. My issue is when i used `form.submit`,I am getting redirected to error page. When I tried with `window.open`, it works. Please help me what is the exact difference between these two. And whether `form.submit` also works here? Please see the Javascript code below. When I uncomment the `window.open` and comment the `frm.submit`, it works.

```
function Check() {
     var frm = document.forms[0];
     var target = frm.target;
     var action = frm.action; 
     var HPPSFeild='<%=HPPSURLFeild.ClientID%>';
     var HPPSValue=document.getElementById (HPPSFeild).getAttribute('value'); 
    frm.target = "_blank";
    frm.action =HPPSValue;
    alert (frm.action);
     frm.submit();
    frm.target = target;
    frm.action = action;
     //window.open(HPPSValue);  
}
```

Comment: `window.open` will make a `GET` request, but depending on the `method` attribute of your `form` the submission may make a `POST` request.

Comment: If you want to know what is different about two requests, then examine them in your browser's developer tools' Net tag or use something like Charles Proxy.

Comment: Oh..may be in form.submit my request will be post.I will check using firebug.Thanks Delan and Quentin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this below code

```
<form action="file.php" method="post" target="foo" onSubmit="window.open('', 'foo',     
'width=450,height=300,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')">
```

---

> That *onSubmit* is helps to call any server side event or javascript function (like Post to a method) , but the windos.open is helps to open next page (same as Response.Redirect in c#`,Like GET a Method )

You need to change

```
//,......code
 frm.submit()
 {
 window.open(HPPSValue);
 }:     
//,......code
```

Comment: So can you tell me how to make the default post request which I have in form.submit function to get in the above javascript

Comment: You need to add 

`frm.submit(){
window.open(HPPSValue);  
}:`

Comment: But there is no need to use both submit and window.open right?. Ofcourse if I use window.open alone,it works. Whether frm submit works without window.open. ?

Comment: window.open is working on when you call that code , but form.submit is works only when you click the submit button on the  page .

Answer (score 1):

> - form.submit();
> - window.open('url');

is same when you using form submit `method=GET`
because `window.open();` always makes **GET** request

but if you are using **POST** method to submit your form then it different from `window.open()` method.

Answer (score 1):

`Form.Submit` will pass input type controls with value to the action URL defined in form and `windows.open` will open new window with given URL

if you want value to be passed to new page I will suggest you to use `form.submit` method

```
<form method='post' action='URL'>
<input type=""
....
....
....
</form>
```

In script when you write `form.submit` it will open URL and value of input type will be passed in query string